# React match is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have app.js with

```
...
<Route path="/order/:id" element={<OrderScreen />}><Route>
...
```

And in screen **OrderScreen.js**:

```
function OrderScreen({match}){
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
dispatch (listOrderDetails(match.params.id))
}, [])
}
........
```

In my actions:

```
.....
export const listOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
try{
   dispatch ({type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST})
   const {data} = await axios.get(`localhost:8000/api/order/${id}`)
......
```

Also django urlpatterns:

```
path('order/<str:pk>/', views.getOrder, name='order')
```

But there is an error **match is undefined**,
where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `useParams` hook to retrieve the `id`:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function OrderScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderDetails(id));
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are defining the Route wrongly... This should work:

```
<Route path="/order/:id" component={OrderScreen} />
```

Refer to the Getting Started docs on Redux for a minimal usage: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data#adding-the-single-post-route